# Ошибка: pygame.error: video system not initialized. почему?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))

while 1:
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i == pygame.quit():
            pygame.quit()
```

Причём ошибку выдает именно в 8-ой строке.

Comment: Потому что вы заканчиваете работу фреймворка внутри проверки )

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))

while 1:
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        print(f'111 {i}') 
        print(f'222 {pygame.event.get()}') 
        print(f'333 {i.type}') 
        print(f'444 {pygame.QUIT}') 
    
#        if i == pygame.quit():
#            pygame.quit()

        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:                          # +++
            sys.exit()                                     # +++
```